# Are there two meanings to ”I saw the same car as her car in the garage”?

Tags: meaning

> I saw the same car as her car in the garage.

I couldn’t understand which car is in this garage the car I saw or her car? Are there two meanings in sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are these "for + nouns" adjectival prepositional phrases or adverbial prepositional ones?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/21640/are-these-for-nouns-adjectival-prepositional-phrases-or-adverbial-prepositio) The issue here is whether ***in the garage*** (adverbially) modifies ***I saw***, or (adjectivally) modifies ***the same car***.

Comment: ...as per the top-voted answer to the earlier question, that potential for ambiguity is exploited by Groucho Marx's well-known gag: *I shot an elephant **in my pyjamas**.  How he got in my pyjamas, I don't know.* Note that in that *exact* context, it wouldn't really make any difference which syntactic parsing applied if he'd said *I shot an elephant **in the garage.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there are two possible meanings:

> I saw the same car as her car in the garage.

1. You saw a car in the garage, and it was the same as "hers".
2. You saw a car somewhere else, and it was the same as the one "she" has in the garage.